# How can I overlay a 'back' and 'next' button on a " pick wifi network " window?

Tags: android

Google play does this when you try to use it and happen to not be connected to a wifi network.

photo of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

If you just run a standard

```
startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
```

Then it loads up the window I'm looking for. However, I want a 'back' and 'next' button overlayed on top of it. Back should return to the previous window and next should only be selectable if a network has been selected and authentication is performed (if required). It would then go to another activity.

I tried implementing it with fragments (one for the intent launched window and another for the button), but it isn't working.

This was the code that launched when the app did

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layfile);
//        Intent n = new Intent(this,Pactivity.class);
//        startActivity(n);
//        
    }
}

public class Pactivity extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    //addPreferencesFromIntent(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}

}

public class Pfrag extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Here are the xml files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    
    <Preference 
        android:key="key"   
        android:title="WiFi" 
        android:summary="Calls WiFi">           
            <intent android:action="android.net.wifi.PICK_WIFI_NETWORK"/>           
    </Preference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I also tried some thrown together Preferences based classes. Also not doing what I want.

How can I get buttons overlayed on to what you see with a `WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK`?

Comment: This is a programming question, more suitable for StackOverflow. This StackExchange is more about Android and maximising the user's usage of Android smartphones/tablets.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);       
    intent.putExtra("only_access_points", true);
    intent.putExtra("extra_prefs_show_button_bar", true);
    intent.putExtra("wifi_enable_next_on_connect", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

This should do it.
Reverse engineered from google code.

Comment: How do you get the picked network? the screen that opens with this intent  doesn't offer a select option. it just lets you manage your connections.

Comment: Depending on what the user has chosen (back or next), you will get your result code. Realize that the user cannot select next till a wifi is selected. Once you get next you can enumerate the wificonnections and check which is connected wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks(); - status

Comment: @uncleking is there a way to remove the back button?

Comment: Any way to open Bluetooth settings like this wifi

Answer (score 3):

This is just an improvement of UncleKing's answer.

Since you ask specifically for

> How can I get buttons overlayed on to what you see with a WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK?

There is no need for the extras `only_access_points` and `wifi_enable_next_on_connect`. You only need the `extra_prefs_show_button_bar` extra. The overlay buttons will appear just by using this last extra.

You can try this using ADB if you want:

```
am start -a android.net.wifi.PICK_WIFI_NETWORK --ez extra_prefs_show_button_bar True
```

So the reduced code would be:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);       
intent.putExtra("extra_prefs_show_button_bar", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Tried it on Android 4.1, 4.4 and 5.1.