# Call wireless settings screen with back button

Tags: android, settings, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-wireless

If there is no wireless connection and no logged in google account when you open Play Market and choose new or existing account it opens specific wireless settings screen with back button at the bottom.
[image: Wireless settings with back button]

How to open same screen from my app?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to open wifi settings on Nook/NookColor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11429090/716075)

Comment: Answer provided with this link didn't work

Comment: Show your code please. And `logcat` output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);       
    intent.putExtra("only_access_points", true);
    intent.putExtra("extra_prefs_show_button_bar", true);
    intent.putExtra("wifi_enable_next_on_connect", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

This should do it. Reverse engineered from google code.

Copied from [How can I overlay a 'back' and 'next' button on a " pick wifi network " window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215473/how-can-i-overlay-a-back-and-next-button-on-a-pick-wifi-network-window).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but maybe with a preference intent. I know you can call other settings with that one.

Comment: You mean I can create custom layout for preferences intent?

Comment: Yes. My book has this example to import system preference screens: <PreferenceScreen
android:title="Intent preference"
android:summary="System preference imported using an intent">
<intent android:action="android.settings.DISPLAY_SETTINGS "/>
</PreferenceScreen>

Comment: btw. the book is Proffecional android 2 application developement.